# Equivalence between formulations of the Nullstellensatz

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, model-theory

I'm trying to undestand two proofs of the Hilbert's Nullstellensatz. One is the model-theoretic version given by Nicolas Ford and the other version is the one given by Terry Tao on his blog. The formulations of the theorem goes as follow

> *(Nicolas Ford)* For $S \subseteq K[\overline{x}]$, let $V(S) = \{ \overline{a} \in K^{n} : f(\overline{a}) = 0, \forall f \in S \}$. If $I \subset J$ are radical ideals, then $V(J) \subset V(I)$

> *(Terry Tao's Blog)* Let $P_1, P_2, \cdots, P_m \in F[X]$ where $X = (x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_d)$, then only one of the following statements holds: i) The system of equations $P_1(x) = \cdots = P_m(x) = 0$, $R(x) \neq 0$ has a solution on $x \in F^{d}$ ii) There exists polynomials $Q_1, \cdots, Q_m \in F[x]$ and a natural number $r$ such that $P_1Q_1 + \cdots + P_mQ_m = R^{r}$

I'm having trouble understanding how are this two formulations telling me similar (the same) things. I would really appreciate if someone could enlighten me. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Ford's statement is the easy half of the Nullstellensatz; Tao's statement is the hard half. So the two are not actually connected.

Comment: @ZhenLin the thing that I can't completely understand is that why if they're the Nullstellensatz those two formulations have such a difference. Thanks for your answer by the way!

Comment: I used the word "is" loosely. One usually reduces the hard half of Nullstellensatz to proving Tao's statement.